# Get handler of UIAlertAction in Swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

How is it possible to get the handler of a `UIAlertAction` in Swift. It is set when initializing however I haven't found any property to get hold on the closure of the action. The closure is of type `(UIAlertAction) -> Void` however I would like to get the content of the closure so that I have some closure like `() -> Void`. Is this possible? Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NO member/property exposed by the UIAlertAction class. However we can manage this by ourselves by subclassing UIAlertAction and have some member named, say, "actionHandler" to store that.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a subclass for this as followed:

```
/// An UIAlertAction which saves the handler. Can be used for unit testing the action callback.
final class UIExecutableAlertAction: UIAlertAction {

    private var handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)?

    static func with(title: String?, style: UIAlertActionStyle, handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) -> UIExecutableAlertAction {
        let action = UIExecutableAlertAction(title: title, style: style, handler: handler)
        action.handler = handler
        return action
    }

    func execute() {
        handler?(self)
    }

}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
let myAction = UIExecutableAlertAction.with(title: "title", style: .destructive, handler: { [weak self] _ in
    // Do something
})
```